# Pass Data from one Method to another

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, youtube-api, afnetworking

I using AFNetworking to populate a UITableView with youtube videos. YouTube API only allows maximum 50 result for each request. So I have to use multiple URLs to get more than 50 results.

I created a Method which will do AFNetworkings AFJSONRequestOperation on the given URLs.

I think the UITable is getting created before i receive the JSON data. Everything was working perfectly before i created the Method.

This the first time i have created a Method. I have been trying to load more than 50 youtube videos on a UITable for the last few days.Please have a look at my code.

Here is my code, you can also download the entire project from

QQViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlAsString = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50";


    // I am not sure how i am supposed to populate the uitableview with the second link :(

     NSString *urlAsString2 = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&start-index=51";



    self.myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

    [self getJSONfromURL:self.myurl];
```

[self.tableView reloadData];

```
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 

        self.videoMetaData = [self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"items.video"];

        NSLog(@" QQVC video Meta Data %@", self.videoMetaData);


        self.allThumbnails = [self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video.thumbnail"];


        // The table need to be reloaded or else we will get an empty table.

        [self.tableView reloadData]; // Must Reload

        // NSLog(@" video Meta Data %@", self.videoMetaData);


}
```

// Here is the Method

```
-(void)getJSONfromURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    // setup AFNetworking stuff
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // call delegate or processing method on success

       // [self.myJSON = (NSArray *)JSON];

        self.myJSON = [JSON valueForKey:@"data"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
       //NSLog(@" in get JSon method %@", self.myJSON);

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];


    [operation start];



}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: After you get the download, you need to call reloadData on your table view again.

Comment: i did reload on viewDidAppear

Comment: But that's probably too early. You need to do it again whenever your download method returns.

Comment: I haven't used AFJSONRequestOperation, so I don't know where the data is returned, but it looks like it's where you have self.myJSON = ... If that's the case, then your reloadData should be there not where you have it now.

Comment: i moved the reload table there. still empty table.

Comment: So what is the actual problem you're seeing? Do you not get any pictures, or only the first set of 50?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24486/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-user1951876)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your reload tableview call to here.

```
-(void)getJSONfromURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    // setup AFNetworking stuff
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // call delegate or processing method on success

       // [self.myJSON = (NSArray *)JSON];

        self.myJSON = [JSON valueForKey:@"data"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
       //NSLog(@" in get JSon method %@", self.myJSON);

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];


    [operation start];



}
```

Comment: Then you probably aren't parsing the JSON properly.

Comment: The can see JSON on the console. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I said you aren't parsing it right. I didn't say you weren't downloading it right.

Answer (score 1):

There were several problems in the getJSONfromURL: method. The main problem was that you were defining self.myJSON as [JSON valueForKey:@"data"], but then defining self.allThumbnails as [self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video.thumbnail"] -- you used "data" again, so self.thumbnails was null. This seems to work ok:

```
-(void)getJSONfromURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    // setup AFNetworking stuff
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.myJSON = [JSON valueForKey:@"data"];
        self.allThumbnails = [self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"items.video.thumbnail"];
        self.videoMetaData = [self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"items.video"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

If you want to load date from multiple URLs, you can do it like this. I added a counter to keep track of the progress through the array of URL strings. The table is reloaded after each download, so it doesn't have to wait for the whole thing to complete before some data shows up.

```
@interface QWViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *urlStrings;
@end

@implementation QWViewController {
    int counter;
}


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    counter = 0;
    NSString *urlAsString = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50";
    NSString *urlAsString2 = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&start-index=51";
    self.urlStrings = @[urlAsString,urlAsString2];
    self.allThumbnails = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.videoMetaData = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self getJSONFromURL:self.urlStrings[0]];
}


-(void)getJSONFromURL:(NSString *) urlString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.myJSON = [JSON valueForKey:@"data"];
        [self.allThumbnails addObjectsFromArray:[self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"items.video.thumbnail"]];
        [self.videoMetaData  addObjectsFromArray:[self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"items.video"]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        counter += 1;
        if (counter < self.urlStrings.count) [self getJSONFromURL:self.urlStrings[counter]];
    }

    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```